# Continuous Communication between C# and C++ application using Named Pipe

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pipe, message

I am new in `IPC`. I have try to create a client server application in which my server is C++ application while client is C#. In this application the Client sends message to the server and according to that message server to the operation.
The server basically sends the image frame to the client.

Using Below code I am able to send single frame to client

**My C++ Code**

```cpp
int _count = 0;
const int _scale = 255;
int _bufferSize = ROW * COL;
UINT8 _imageBuffer[391680];
Mat _image;
std::cout << "Server Starting\n";
HANDLE hPipe1 = CreateNamedPipe(_T("\\\\.\\pipe\\HyperPipe1"),
    PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
    PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,
    PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,
    4096,
    4096,
    0,
    NULL);
std::cout << "Server Created Succesfully\n";
ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe1, NULL);
std::cout << "Sending Frame to Client";
_image = imread("C:\\Users\\Chandrapal Singh\\Desktop\\New folder\\Image.bmp", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
//_image.clone().convertTo(_image, CV_16U, _scale);
for (int _imageRow = 0; _imageRow < _image.rows; _imageRow++)
{
    for (int _imageCol = 0; _imageCol < _image.cols; _imageCol++)
    {
        _imageBuffer[_count] = _image.at<UINT8>(_imageRow, _imageCol);
        _count++;
    }
}
DWORD bytesWritten = 0;
WriteFile(hPipe1, _imageBuffer, sizeof(_imageBuffer) * sizeof(UINT8), &bytesWritten, NULL);
```

**My C# Code**

```cs
int _imageRowSize = 544;
int _imageColSize = 720;
int _count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[_imageColSize * _imageRowSize];
Image<Gray, Byte> image = new Image<Gray, Byte>(_imageColSize,_imageRowSize);
Console.WriteLine("Creating Client Pipe");
NamedPipeClientStream pipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "HyperPipe1", PipeDirection.InOut);
Console.WriteLine("Pipe Created Successfully, Connecting to Server");
pipe.Connect();
Console.WriteLine("Successfully, Connected to Server");
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    while (true)
    {
        _count = 0;      
        int read = pipe.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        for (int _imageRow = 0; _imageRow < 544; _imageRow++)
        {
            for (int _imageCol = 0; _imageCol < 720; _imageCol++)
            {
                try
                {
                    image.Data[_imageRow, _imageCol, 0] = buffer[_count];
                }catch(Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                }
                _count++;
            }
        }
        CvInvoke.Imshow("Image", image);
        Console.WriteLine(_count);
        if (read <= 0)
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to know how to send Message from C# to C++ and how my C++ continuously send image frames to C#.

Comment: Remember that there is a limit to how much data you can send atomically in a single message through a pipe. Look up `PIPE_BUF`.

Comment: OP, see my reply on the comments to @dev65. You can just do multiple client requests and have the server check the client buffer being sent to see which frame is being requested, or use virtual memory operations to pass buffers too large for a named pipe buffer. Alternatively, look into the undocumented ALPC mechanism for sharing sections of memory (which Microsoft internally rely on in sub-systems like csrss). For you, the client request (multiple times) or virtual memory method (with the named pipes) is likely ideal.

Comment: For the virtual memory operations method, you do not need to do anything complicated. You can use VirtualAllocEx and WriteProcessMemory, then pass the pointer of where the large buffer is stored under the context of the client process's virtual memory via the named pipe - the address will be the one returned from VirtualAllocEx (will be valid in client process's virtual memory only, since you'd be passing a handle to client process for the process handle argument).

Answer (score -3):

Create two instances of the pipe or another pipe in both server and client and use threads to read and write at the same time without blocking another running operations